# Value and class name with the same value - webpack - css-loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

I have the following component in react:

`component.js`

```js
import styles from './styles.css';

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    return <div className={`${styles["container"]}`}>Hey :D</div>
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`styles.css`

```css
@value container: #f5f5f5;

.container {
    background-color: red;
}

.unique-class {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

As you can see, I have a value and a class with the same name. Everything works fine if I do `styles["unique-class"]`, I mean, I get the transformed class name. The problem comes when I do `styles["container"]`. In that case, I'm getting the string `#f5f5f5`, which makes sense because it's the value of the value `container`. But what I want is the transformed class name of `.container`!

This is the part of the webpack config doing the transformation:

```js
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@rmwc'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-image-lightbox/style.css'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/js/src/modules/Common/styles/material.css'),
                ],
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: { localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },
                        },
                    }],
            },
```

I suppose that maybe is there a way to access values in `styles` variable. I do not know if this is even possible, maybe avoid `@values` from getting in the `styles` variable. What do you think?